# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle xcode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I created a new Empty project in Xcode, I added a new storyboard and added some view controllers too. The first a TableViewController which I Embedded into a Navigation controller and the other a normal ViewController. I then selected the navigation view controller and checked is initial view controller in the attribute inspector. When I ran the app I got this:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'Storyboard''

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: did u set the storyboard in the project settings ?

Comment: Yes I did set it to be main interface

Comment: can u show the screnshot of the storyboard, and the main interface settings ? Also do u have any code in appdelegate ?

Answer (score 1):

Once you create a new `storyboard`, you need to provide its info to the project settings.

[image]

Once you do this, you should also look into the target membership!!!

Select your `storyboard`, and see if you have the target membership unchecked in the file inspector.If it is unchecked, then your target membership is not set. YOu need to check it to make your target membership set!!!:

[image]

Also check in the `Copy bundle resources` setting in the `Build phase`.You need to set your storyboard file in here too:

[image]

Comment: I have the target membership checked

Comment: Do you have the storyboard file set in copy bundle resuorces in the build phase settings ?@T.Israel

Comment: I have that too copied

Comment: Can you share the screenshots/sourcecode of your project ?

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=563EFA227C7FB399!15213&authkey=!AEUzcufiE-2sdeI&ithint=folder%2c

Comment: do u have teamviewer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96170/discussion-between-t-israel-and-mr-t).

Answer (score 0):

In your Info.plist you probably have a value called "Main nib file base name". You have to replace it with "Main storyboard file base name" with the value "Storyboard". That's what I saw when I downloaded your project. This may solve your issue